# Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field imce drupal

Tags: files

I'm in trouble so maybe someone can figure it out: I'm trying to have singular folder for every user in imce (drupal7) and I want that the folder is a code that I can insert with a field in user profile. (like 78M4589)

well, this code generate the folder in the right place:

```
return 'users/'.$user->field_code['und'][0]['value'];
```

but in imce on the page i have this notice:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field_code in eval() (linea 1 di () : eval()'d code).

I really can't figure it out.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly you are not able to figure out? There is no `field_code` in `$user`, simple as that. Maybe you forgot to declare it `global` first, or something?

Comment: thank you, i created e new field [field_code] on user registration form, yeah it's probably i forgot something. to declare it [global] first, how can i do that?

Comment: `global $user;` before the place you want to use `$user`? Just to be sure. Don't know if that's the reason, but it's my best guess now. Also, try to `var_dump($user);` if `global` will not help.

Comment: ok, with 'var_dump($user);' i understand that the field can't be used: 'object(stdClass)#9 (23) { ["uid"]=> string(2) "48" ["name"]=> string(15) "michel3" ["mail"]=> string(0) "" ["theme"]=> string(0) "" ["signature"]=> string(0) "" ["signature_format"]=> string(10) "clean_html" ["created"]=> string(10) ...' can i insert also the field i created?

Answer (score 1):

The global $user object is not guaranteed to have all the fields loaded onto it.

Try specifically loading the user like this:

```
global $user;
// Load the full user object.
$account = user_load($user->uid);
// Get the user code.
$code = '';
if ($items = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_code')) {
  $code = $items[0]['value'];
}
return $code;
```